# Как отобразить блок в  bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, html

Собственно, вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_K88/7k3h2jea/2/), но нужно добавить дополнительные блоки с классами `.well`, `.alert`, `.alert-block`. Это будет выглядеть так:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="span12 tab-pane" id="0">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="alert alert-block" id="0">
                <p>0</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@little_boy](/users/3662/little_boy)](/users/3662/little_boy), если вы пытались сделать вложенный таб, то вы допустили следующую ошибку: содержимое таба добавили, а управляющие элементы нет. Плюс атрибут ID не может начинаться с цифры и должен быть уникальным.

Собрал для вас **[рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/7k3h2jea/4/)**